# MySQL INNODB SELECT query hanging on copying to tmp table

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5

I have a query that is hanging (seemingly) randomly on a specific query.  Most of my website users do not have a problem when this query runs but a few users are having timeout issues on the website and when I check the `processlist` it gets stuck on `copying to tmp table`.

I believe the hard drive is just not keeping up, which is causing the hang on the copying to tmp table.

I don't believe I can optimize the query any more efficiently.  I was wondering if I could set up my server's second hard drive as the temp table storage so that way I'm spreading out some of the load being put on the server.

```
The query:
SELECT DISTINCT  
    activity_seismo_info.ID, 
    activity_seismo_info.CREATED_AT, 
    activity_seismo_info.UPDATED_AT, 
    ....    
    activity_seismo_info.ASI_EXTRA_5, 
    seismo.ID, 
    ....    
    seismo.SEISMO_NOTES 

FROM `activity_seismo_info` 
    JOIN activity_info ON (activity_seismo_info.ASI_ACTIVITY_ID=activity_info.ID) 
    JOIN location ON (activity_info.ACTIVITY_LOCATION_ID=location.ID) 
    LEFT JOIN seismo ON (activity_seismo_info.ASI_SEISMO_ID=seismo.ID) 

WHERE location.ID='193' 

ORDER BY activity_info.ACTIVITY_EVENT_TIME DESC LIMIT 30
```

I am on a P4 with 2GB RAM and two hard drives (the second hard drive is not used)

PHP5.2

MySQL 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.4

symfony 1.2 application with Propel

**UPDATE**

thanks to @DTest's suggestion, I found my query was returning all the rows in the table before running a limit on the result.  But for future reference, is there a way to setup MySQL to use a second hard drive as the 'scratch' drive for temp tables?

Comment: can you show the `EXPLAIN` output of the query?

Comment: doing the `EXPLAIN` I think I've found the problem.  The main table being returned `activity_seismo_info` has 382000 rows and I believe it's copying all that data to the tmp table.  I thought the `LIMIT` would have prevented that...

Comment: Interesting. I'm not an expert with the various buffers, but perhaps tuning `join_buffer_size` variable will help? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size

Comment: You'll probably want to ask a new question regarding the separate hard drive for temp tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `my.cnf` use this option

`tmpdir=/tmp` (this is the default anyway, just choose another folder)

Restart of mysql required

BTW since the `location.ID` is `'193'` why even involve the location table ???

Try the following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    activity_seismo_info.ID, 
    activity_seismo_info.CREATED_AT, 
    activity_seismo_info.UPDATED_AT, 
    #....    
    activity_seismo_info.ASI_EXTRA_5, 
    seismo.ID, 
    #....    
    seismo.SEISMO_NOTES

FROM `activity_seismo_info`
    JOIN activity_info ON (activity_seismo_info.ASI_ACTIVITY_ID=activity_info.ID)
    JOIN (SELECT ID from location WHERE ID='193') location ON (activity_info.ACTIVITY_LOCATION_ID=location.ID)
    LEFT JOIN seismo ON (activity_seismo_info.ASI_SEISMO_ID=seismo.ID) 
;
```

Comment: unfortunately the way the database is designed, the `activity_seismo_info` table is not tied to `location`, it is tied to the `seismo` table which is tied to the `location`.  I am looking at denormalizing to an extent the next iteration of the database to remove the circuitous queries I sometimes have to make

Comment: @Patrick I used your original query but slid the "location.ID='193'" clause into the location alias. Please see if that changes the EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: well, it did knock the massive row result to about 40% of the original(382000 -> 150400), but I think the way to truly cut the return down to an appropriate size would be to run a subselect ala `SELECT seismo.id FROM seismo WHERE seismo.seismo_location_id = '193';`.  Only problem, I've never done much with subselects and can't seem to get them to work.